# matchMedia returns null when the FireBug is enabled

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, media-queries

My web application uses `matchMedia`. Sometimes call of this function returns `null` no matter what value is passed. It is strange but it happens not always (maybe 1 of 3 times) and only in FireFox with opened FireBug. Did anybody face with such issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that matchMedia() returns null in FF when it's called in a hidden (display: none) iframe.
I've encountered this behavior when I've used jQuery UI's tabs widget, and the tab panels were iframes. My workaround was to override the jQuery UI's .ui-tabs-hide CSS class:

```
.ui-tabs-hide { display: block !important; position: absolute; left: -99999px; }
```

Comment: This is one of the strangest bugs I've come across! We used a absolutely positioned div on top of the iFrame to hide its content.

Comment: 100 plus likes for you

Answer (score 3):

Matchmedia returns null in case of hidden iframe, You can use this code before accessing window.matchmedia

`if(typeof window.matchMedia == 'function' && window.matchMedia!=undefined && window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 650px)')!=null){
//Your code goes here
}`

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to do this:

```
if (w.matchMedia == null ){ 
    format = uformat; 
} else if(w.matchMedia(qo) != null) {
    if (w.matchMedia(qo).matches || w.matchMedia(q).matches ) {  format = mformat; }
} else {
    format = uformat; 
}
```