# Stripe Payment Gateway issue ruby on rails (TypeError: window. multimedia (...) is null)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

### Got this error on firebug console => (TypeError: window.matchMedia(...) is null)

---

When I click on the paywithcard button than I will get (TypeError: window. multimedia (...) is null) on firebug console.

**button.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag front_charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: <%=@cart_totals%></span>
    </label>
  </article>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Stripe.api_key = "pk_test_******************" %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="<%=@cart_totals%>"
          data-locale="auto"></script>

<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var widthQuery = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)");

</script>
```

**Stripe.rb**

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['pk_test_****************'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['sk_test_************']
}


Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_****************"
```

**Charges_controller.rb**

```
class Front::ChargesController < ApplicationController
layout 'product'
def new
end

def create  
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:ronakabhattrz],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'INR'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end



end
```

Comment: Seems like you are having trouble with `var widthQuery = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)");` this line of code. Remove it for check.

Comment: still got same error

Comment: Try defining it before creating your widthQuery variable `var window.matchMedia = {}`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a die hard bug in FF.

Check [matchMedia returns null when the FireBug is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056313/matchmedia-returns-null-when-the-firebug-is-enabled) for work around